Starfield Sarah seriously sabotaging stealth
I'm on Mars and trying to stealthily clear out a spacers' base but Sarah keeps charging in shooting and screwing up my stealth. At this point in the game I don't have the option to get rid of her.
I understand there should be a conversation option to tell her to wait but unfortunately the conversation seems to be stuck on the final conversation back at the Lodge (where you tell her if you're ready to go or want to do some other stuff first).
Can anyone suggest some console commands to help out with this?

+1 for alliteration (and also being a good question). Can you tell us what the last/current conversation options are exactly?

Appreciated :-) well I'm not currently home where my PC is but there's three options. First is to go ahead with the story mission. Second is that you want more time to do other stuff first. I think the third was some general conversation, maybe requesting more info about Mars, herself or Constellation.

Normally you'd indeed tell her to wait, and that's the only real option you have apart from dismissing her as a companion entirely.
In your case, you might have to go back to the lodge and complete that stuck conversation. Not sure it'll work but it's worth a try.
Last resort, load an older safe from before that conversation got stuck and lose some progress (hopefully not too much).
By the way, there are other places where Sarah (and I guess other companions too) do stupid things, like barging into a room full of NPCs when you're trying to sneak your way around the place. Ryujin spy missions, cough cough.

I actually did make a manual "never overwrite this" save right before giving her the go-ahead. Just because I hate having companions forced on me and want to always lone wolf it. Appreciate the game warning me but don't appreciate it being forced to begin with. But yeah, I'm not OK with losing the progress I've made since then. Might look at console commands instead. tai and setav aggression 0 look promising or there's a mod for improved companion behaviour (though of the whole two mods I installed so far, one broke the game so adding another mod goes in the maybe pile).

@Sam for some quests it's understandable you're forced to have a specific companion. For example the first Constellation quest with Sarah she's effectively vetting you to see if you're suitable for membership. And the quest lines resulting in marriage proposals speak for themselves too.

I think I might give the rest of the story missions a miss to be honest. I usually do in Bethesda games. I'm only doing this because so many "tips, tricks and advice for Starfield" type articles told me to do the main mission line until I unlock some special powers. I usually avoid spoilers but I'll look into these powers to decide if it's even worth it. Far prefer the freedom to explore and do what I want.

@Sam some arcs give nice rewards. E.g. the Rangers arc gives a good ship.

Yeah I wouldn't mind that actually. I care far more about the surface exploration than space sim side (nothing will beat Freelancer for that) so guns is what I really want, but I still have to get from planet A to planet B of course without getting blown up.

@Sam I know what you mean. I tend to use whatever I can capture until I have enough money to build a very large ship with enough cargo capacity to hold the museum's worth of weapons and space suits I loot along the way. Think 12000-15000 cargo space, 70+ agility, and max jump range.
